# I need to store HTML emails in a database. Is that a bad idea?

Tags: sql, redundancy

The templates for these HTML emails are all the same, but there are just different variables for say, first name, last name and such.

Would it just make sense to store the most minimal of data that I need, and load the template in and replace the variables everytime?

Another option would be to actually create the HTML file and store a reference to it, which probably would be the easiest to do except it might be a pain managing the files, and it adds complexity in regards to migrating, file permissions, et cetera.

Looking for opinions from people who've done this before...

**GOAL/PURPOSE/USE:**

I have a booking engine. When users make a booking, they are sent a confirmation email, generated from the sessionized booking data.

This email provides a "Cannot view this email? See it here" link which provides a web view of the email, in addition to a plaintext view.

I need to display the same email that was sent out, in addition to the plaintext view.

The template is subject to change, but I think because of that very fact I should have a table of templates and map the data to a template.

Comment: Store for what purpose? Archiving? Sending them later? Editing? What should happen if the template is changed? Needs more info IMO

Comment: @Pekka - Ah, I forgot. Updating.

Answer (score 0):

That's what I would do, because the template layout may change over the time, but the person information should remain the same. So, it makes sense to just store the person information in the database and leave the template out from the database.

In fact, it would be even better if you use template engine such as Velocity (in Java) to construct your HTML emails... very easy, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

On the one hand cpu is more expensive then memory, so mostly it is better to save more data to reduce cpu power used by computation. 
But in your case, I would save the minimal data, the emails or what you are tying to save, because it allows you to easily remodel your templates, and to reuse the data at multiple places of your application.

Answer (score 0):

You persist redundant data (especially because of the template) which is in no way normalized. I would not suggest to do that. But mentioned in the comment it is important what you want to do with that data.

If you only save the data you need you could for example exchange that template easy and use another one.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, your right on track. I did a similar thing. All dynamic/runtime variables were starting from **@@symbol**.

So in database you would have one Template table. One table would be for dynamic/runtime variables. One table for Mapping between Template and dynamic/runtime variables.

**tblTemplate** - TemplateID, TemplateValue
**tblRuntimeVariables** - RuntimeVariableID, VariableString, VariableSQL
**tblMapping** - TemplateID, RuntimeVariableID, RuntimeVariableValue

Advantage of using an extra mapping table is that on adding new dynamic variables to existing change would mean making no change to existing database. Only more rows would be added to tblMapping.

In my case I was also having one extra column for storing SQL Statements in tblRuntimeVariables in **case the value for a runtime variable is fetched from database**.